# mysql default sort order with specific selects

Tags: mysql

I get a lot of answers when it comes to how MySQL sorts results but none seems to address my specific issue. Hope I didn't miss the answer somewhere else here on stackoverflow.

I have an SQL query that looks like this:

```
SELECT id, something FROM sometable WHERE 
id=1 OR id=2 OR id=5 OR 
id=6 OR id=100 OR id=1000 
OR id=4
```

Now I need it to return the results in the specific order it has been selected. The results should look like this in this specific order:

```
1
2
5
6
100
1000
4
```

Will MYSQL display the returned records in this particular order the way I selected them? I cannot use ORDER BY because I need them the exact way I selected them in the first instance. A simple test confirms that it is returned in this way but from reading elsewhere I get the idea that you cannot trust the way results are being returned in specific order when ORDER BY is not used.

Comment: Couldn't you use `ORDER BY field(id, 1, 2, 5, 6, 100, 1000, 4);` to get the intended result? Or could you explain a little more why you can't use `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`FIELD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function. In your application code, where you will be creating this SQL dynamically, you can build the SQL string in the same order for `FIELD()`, as in your `WHERE` clause.

```
FIELD(str,str1,str2,str3,...)
```

> Returns the index (position) of str in the str1, str2, str3, ... list.
>   Returns 0 if str is not found.

Now, the `FIELD(id, 1,2,5,6,100,1000,4)` function will return **0** if the `id` is not in `(1,2,5,6,100,1000,4)`.

So, if we use `ORDER BY FIELD(id, 1,2,5,6,100,1000,4)` only, other **non-matching** rows will appear at the top. So, we can use [`If()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function to return **1** for the other **non-matching** rows, and **0** for the matched rows.

Now, we can utilize one more level of ordering by `FIELD(id, 1,2,5,6,100,1000,4)`. This will ensure that the matched id(s) appear first in the order as specified in the `Field()` function.

```
SELECT id, something FROM sometable WHERE 
id=1 AND id=2 AND  id=5 AND  
id=6 AND  id=100 AND id=1000 
AND id=4 
ORDER BY IF(FIELD(id, 1,2,5,6,100,1000,4) = 0, 1, 0) ASC, 
         FIELD(id, 1,2,5,6,100,1000,4) ASC
```